# Swagger/OAS Schema design discussion

Tags: swagger, schema, openapi, jsonschema, api-documentation

## **Background:**

We support an API guide directory where we document and show the different web services present in our system. There are many containers that group related services and few services have a common schema/model.
For ex, ignore the identifier as this is an excample
create a person - POST - [name, email, age]
get all persons - GET - list of [name, email, age]

The 2 calls above have the same model,

```
        "name" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "description" : "name of the persion"
        },
        "email" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "description" : "user email id",
          "example" : "abcd@def.com"
        },
        "age" : {
          "type" : "integer",
          "description" : "user age",
          "example" : 20
        }
```

## **Question:**

We have been using the same schema against both GET/POST calls so far, and now we want to add additional validations that may exist on fields, for example, name cannot contain numbers..

```
        "name" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "description" : "name of the persion",
          **"validation" : "name cannot contain numbers"**
        },
        "email" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "description" : "user email id",
          "example" : "abcd@def.com"
        },
        "age" : {
          "type" : "integer",
          "description" : "user age",
          "example" : 20
        }
```

As you can see this validation makes sense on POST requests only and not on get requests,

## **Solutions:**

So, what is a good design in this case?

1. Have separate snippets for GET and POST?(one without the validation and one with))
2. Keep the validation and maintain only one schema and let user see the extra field?

Any industry standards documented? any experiences/ examples? Just interested in getting some thoughts!

Opening discussion to learn and discuss what a better design would be for a problem many might have faced or will face.

Comment: I'm confused why the JSON payload would be carrying validations.  Is this a client side validation that you're reporting back to the server?

Comment: Can you explain why you think request and response payloads cannot both have validation applied in the same manner?

Comment: @gregsdennis  This is a server side validation that client side would not be knowing.

Comment: @JeremyFiel In the above example, "name cannot contain numbers" what would the user do with this data when referring to the GET example? 
The same line on the POST example would warn him to use correct data following correct practices. 

Again as a I said, my option 2, there is no harm in having that field on GET schema, just not as relevant

Comment: The response payload can be validated by the server using the same schema. It can also indicate to a client the intentions of the payload when receiving a response. They may never use the POST operation.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the schema that has the common elements, then create other schemas that define the additional elements.

So if your common model is defined like

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    common:
      type: object
      properties:
        foo:
          type: string
```

you can create a secondary schema that references that one and adds other elements, even to pre-existing properties.

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    common:
      type: object
      properties:
        foo:
          type: string
    common-with-validation:
      allOf:
        - $ref: #/components/schemas/common
        - properties:
            foo:
              maxLength: 50
```

In this document, the `common-with-validation` schema starts with the `common` schema and adds a `maxLength` to the existing requirements on the `foo` property.  I don't need to re-specify that the payload is an object or that `foo` is a string because the reference already does those things.

Comment: If pincode is a property that has a custom validation, this field can belong to billing address, shipping address etc. So there would be a duplication to add billing-with-validation (validation rules) and shipping-with-validation (validation rules) and so on. 
But definitely a clean solution, Thank you!